# Do debug messages being displayed on production server?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have console handler that prints `DEBUG` messages to console.

On production server where `DEBUG=False`, do debug messages displayed on console? Or they're only valid on development machine.

Comment: `print` is fine for local debugging, but not in production. Instead, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/

Comment: When DEBUG=False on production you can't see the error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Django prints to apache's `error.log` when DEBUG=False.

Comment: is it possible to turn debug log message off on production?
in Django 1.5 such option available but not in Django 1.4

Answer (score 0):

When DEBUG=False Error messages wont appear on site.You will get email to mails listed in 'ADMINS' settings in the "settings.py" file.

Comment: I meant DEBUG messages not ERROR messages.
I don't want debug message to be printed to console on production

Comment: Then insted of printing the messages you have to log them into a log file.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/